# How to determine the order of transaction input (in the order of the TxIds)?

Tags: cardano-cli, script

If I have the following transaction:

```
cardano-cli transaction build                 \
--tx-in dd3dbc1cbd4627da3b74fae8c7bcc3f05f3b41ec36feb33f81cf885390b634d6#0      \
--tx-in 40917b278a9bf960fcc0a3de9eb5945113c025323d7d73c19dd6d26cfe92e04b#0      \
--tx-in e98a07b5ff0b048950ce4ffdfbfb53def61e2b52e9bf39cdd82b3eb91c40e2a6#0 \
--tx-in-script-file plutus/order-v11-buy-token.plutus   \
--tx-in-datum-file 'tmp/batch_datum_file_0.json'   \
--tx-in-redeemer-file 'plutus/match-order-redeemer.json'  \
--tx-in 2c759a6606692c021c266025cbd569a1b451e184fb44e001d18152528a3a2161#0 \
--tx-in-script-file plutus/order-v11-buy-token.plutus   \
--tx-in-datum-file 'tmp/batch_datum_file_1.json'   \
--tx-in-redeemer-file 'plutus/match-order-redeemer.json'  \
--tx-in cfbf555aebbf879e2313c32f4d8b839d63d7f7b12fd1027cb3ccd7e9f790e014#0 \
--tx-in-script-file plutus/order-v11-buy-ada.plutus   \
--tx-in-datum-file 'tmp/batch_datum_file_2.json'   \
--tx-in-redeemer-file 'plutus/match-order-redeemer.json'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for transaction input 0 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The provided Plutus code called 'error'.
Script debugging logs: 
the script for transaction input 4 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The provided Plutus code called 'error'.
```

How to realize which scripts reported the error, it is saying `the script for transaction input 0` and `the script for transaction input 4` but with the above command, I cannot find on tx-in position 0 any script. How to determine the order of transaction input (in the order of the TxIds)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all `--tx-in` is not in the order like it is provided in `cardano-cli` command and rather is order ascending by transaction id.

Comment: Not very intuitive behavior. Where did you find that answer?

Comment: I just guess it, and then I did sort utxos and that proved my assumption.

Comment: I created a PR in the `cardano-node` repo to make the errors more explicit: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/pull/3811